# Proving that a set of vectors spans a column space of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Given that A $\in$ M $_{mxn}$ (**R**). Assume that {$v_1$...$v_n$} is a basis for $R^n$ such that {$v_1$...$v_k$} is a basis for Null(A).

How would I prove that {A$v_{k+1}$...A$v_n$} spans Col(A)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column space of matrix $A$ is equivalent to the range of the matrix. That is, if $A:V\to W$, then $$Col(A)=\{w\in W:\:\exists v\in V: Av=w\}.$$ 
Colloquially, the column space (or range) is the set of vectors which are "hit" by the linear transformation represented by the matrix.

Now you haven't showed what you have tried, so I don't know what your level is, but here's a fairly basic proof. From the Rank-Nullity Theorem, we know that
$$ \dim(V)=\dim(Col(A))+\dim(Null(A)).$$
Because $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ is a basis for $V$, and $\{v_1,\ldots,v_k\}$ is basis for $Null(A)$, by the Rank-Nullity Theorem, we can see that 
$$\dim(Col(A))=\dim(V)-\dim(Null(A))=n-k.$$
If we can show that $\{v_{k+1},\ldots,v_n\}$ is linearly independent, it must span $Col(A)$. Fortunately, another result states that any list of linearly independent vectors that contains no elements of $Null(A)$ remains linearly independent under $A$.

So, because $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ is a basis, $\{v_1,\ldots,v_k\}$ being a basis for $Null(A)$ implies that $\{v_{k+1},\ldots,v_n\}\not\in Null(A)$. (Can you show why?) So, $\{A(v_{k+1}),\ldots,A(v_n)\}$ is linearly independent in $Col(A)$ with length equal to $\dim(Col(A))$. Thus, $\{A(v_{k+1}),\ldots,A(v_n)\}$ is a basis for $Col(A)$ and also spans $Col(A)$.

Comment: I understand your proof up until "because {v1,…,vn}{v1,…,vn} is a basis, {v1,…,vk}{v1,…,vk} being a basis for Null(A)Null(A) implies that {vk+1,…,vn}∉Null(A)". I'm so sorry, but I don't know how to show how this happens.

Comment: It follows from the fact that $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ being a basis implies that it is a linearly independent list. Then $span(\{v_1,\ldots,v_k\})=null(A)$, but from linear independence of the original basis $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$, we know that $v_j\in\{v_{k+1},\ldots,v_n\}\implies v_j\not\in span(\{v_1,\ldots,v_k\}=null(A).$

Comment: Using the rank nullity theorem to prove this seems a bit heavy-handed; in fact, this fact can be used to *prove* the rank-nullity theorem.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let $y = Ax$ be an arbitrary element of the column space. By definition of basis, there are coefficients $a_i$ such that
$$
x = a_1v_1 + \cdots + a_n v_n
$$
Using the information from the question, show that 
$$
y = Ax = a_{k+1}(Av_{k+1}) + \cdots + a_{n}(A v_{n})
$$
Because we were able to select such coefficients $a_{k+1},\dots,a_{n}$, we can now say that $y$ is in the span of the vectors $\{Av_{k+1}, \dots, Av_n\}$.